# Switch string c language

Tags: c, string, char

I have this program, which I want to understand the following output:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
void fastSwap (char **i, char **d) 
{ 
  char *t = *d; 
  *d = *i; 
  *i = t; 
} 
int main () 
{ 
 char num1[] = "hellohello"; 
 char num2[] = "classclass"; 
 fastSwap ((char**)&num1,(char**)&num2); 
 printf ("%s\n",num1); 
 printf ("%s\n",num2); 
 return 0; 
}
```

The output will change only `sizeof(void*)` chars, instead of the entire array.

why does this happen?

`&num1` is `char**`, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> &num1 is char** isn't it?

It's `char (*)[11]`. The fact that you casted to `char **` clobbered the warnings of the compiler.

What you are doing is thoroughly undefined behavior. You can't make `num1` point somewhere else because it doesn't point anywhere to begin with: it's an array, not a pointer.

#### EDIT

As Paul R points out, here's what is probably happening. The first `sizeof(char *)` characters of each string are interpreted as a pointer and then those are swapped. What happens essentially depends on the size of the pointer on your implementation. It's quite interesting, however I'm pretty sure it still qualifies as undefined.

Comment: I thought that too at first, but actually I think it's treating the first 4 or 8 characters of each string as if it were a pointer and swapping these, so on a 64 bit system the output is `classclalo` and `hellohelss`

Comment: @PaulR I just tried the thing, indeed I think you're right. Still, this can't be relied upon, right ?

Comment: I *think* it's actually OK and not UB, but it's very ugly. I guess it's just a puzzle that is designed to confuse on first reading.

Comment: @cnicutar but why did we get this output? i mean why is it actually replace with the sizeof(void*) length?

Comment: @PaulR Hard to say but I'll go with you on this one.

Comment: @Itzik984 Try `printf("%p\n%p\n", (void *)num1, (void *)&num1);`. The answer will come to you.

Comment: @cnicutar i understand they have the same address, but still, i dont understand why it will change some chars (sizeof(void*))?

Comment: @Itzik984 Read the edit. 4/8 characters are interpreted as a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in some other posts, num1 and num2 are arrays, not pointers to strings.
It looks like the intention is to swap 2 char pointers.
So rewriting to something like this should work.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
void fastSwap (char **i, char **d) 
{ 
  char *t = *d; 
  *d = *i; 
  *i = t; 
} 
int main () 
{ 
 char * num1 = "hellohello"; // Note making a pointer rather than array.
 char * num2 = "classclass"; 
 fastSwap (&num1,&num2); // Shouldn't need the casts.
 printf ("%s\n",num1); 
 printf ("%s\n",num2); 
 return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should either exchange the values of the pointers themselves (but they are not pointers but arrays) or use a for loop to swap each character one by one (or use a C function like strcpy/strncpy to do the swap and use an external variable above as temporary variable).

Answer (score 0):

If you print the pointer values of num1 and &num1, you will get the same value. So you will basically copy the (char**)size first bytes, that's all.

An array is not a pointer. It can operate the same for many operations, but it is not.
It's rather sure that the compiler directly stores the position of the array in the code, instead of storing the pointer to the data in a char**pointer.